# Get value attribute for each tag found using Tag.find_all()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've generated a list with all tags of my HTML file called 'option'. But I can't get the values inside the tag.

This is my code and data:

```
>>> soup2 = soup.findAll('option')
>>> soup2

[
  <option value="ufs_munic">&nbsp;&nbsp;Por Município&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>,
  <option value="ext_paises">&nbsp;&nbsp;Por País&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>,
  ...
]
```

I'd like to get the quoted values after `option value=` in each tag.

For example:

```
ufs_munic
ext_paises
5
6
7
8
9
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a **list comprehension**, you can get all the values from the options using the `get` method:

```
>>> soup2 = [option.get('value') for option in soup.findAll('option')]
>>> soup2
['ufs_munic', 'ext_paises', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ...]
```

You can even pass a default value if the option has no option defined:

```
option.get('value', 'There is no value!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for item in soup2:
...     print item['value']
```