# Parsing a web form using Beautifulsoup 4 and Python 2.7

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have the below code that parses HTML to extract the form fields of a URL:-

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.myurl.com"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("./test.html").read());
for tag in soup.find_all('option'):
    print tag
```

The above returns the below:

```
<option selected="" value="">any</option>
<option value="4">cars</option>
<option value="61">Â· motorbikes</option>
<option value="5">Â· boats</option>
<option value="17">planes</option>
<option value="40">Â· submarines</option>
```

What I'm looking to do is create a dictionary so that, the key will be, for example '4' and the value will be 'cars'. So, each option value is a key and the description is the value.

I was considering doing some slicing (ie. slicing from character 14 through to X to get the number) but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this. Also, I'm looking to ignore the first line returned also. I only want to parse the "option value" into the dictionary and not "option selected". Also, as can be seen, some values / descriptions are preceded with `"Â· "` - I'd look to ignore this too.

Any assistance can be offered?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027737/get-value-attribute-for-each-tag-found-using-tag-find-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to find all `option` elements that have `value` and doesn't have `selected` attribute; use a dictionary comprehension to make a dictionary:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = u"""
<select>
    <option selected="" value="">any</option>
    <option value="4">cars</option>
    <option value="61">Â· motorbikes</option>
    <option value="5">Â· boats</option>
    <option value="17">planes</option>
    <option value="40">Â· submarines</option>
</select>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print {option['value']: option.text.lstrip(u"Â· ") 
       for option in soup.find_all('option', value=True, selected=False)}
```

Prints:

```
{
    '61': u'motorbikes', 
    '5': u'boats', 
    '4': u'cars', 
    '17': u'planes', 
    '40': u'submarines'
}
```